# Flying AirAsia with an e-boarding pass requiring a documents check

Tags: international-travel

I have a connecting flight through an Indian airport on an AirAsia flight, which is a different airline from my first flight. I had already printed my electronic boarding pass. However, it is mentioned on the boarding pass that I must proceed to the document check counter for verification of entry requirements. Do I have to go through immigration to the check-in counter to verify my documents, or can I do it at the boarding gate?

Comment: For clarity, is this an airside transit with the same airline?

Comment: different airline.

Comment: Where are you travelling from/to?  Which Indian airport is your transit point? Will you have hold baggage?

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is possible to do it at boarding gate (but please: before boarding start). Often, if there are many transfer passengers, they will put an additional booth before the boarding control. Or sometime there is a designed area near boarding, and only verified people can enter.

How? An "ok sign" on a boarding pass (so they may issue one just for that) or on the baggage receipt, or just a paper. Or a sticker on the passport.

In any case: as soon there are crew on boarding gate, ask them.